# Why does jQuery work in jSfiddle but not site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery to change the height of a div, I was using static values before that were set by me, but now I made one that makes the div to its full height and returns it to 24px, Now it works great in JSFiddle but not on the site.

```
jQuery(".dsellactiontext").toggle(function(){
jQuery(this.parentNode).animate({
    height: $(this.parentNode)[0].scrollHeight+'px'
  }, 400);
},function(){
jQuery(this.parentNode).animate({height:24},600);
});
```

The fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/skoltyno/ZBR8G/

The site test page : http://bocaratonrealestatemarket.com/jquery-test-page/

You can see in the inspector that the height is not being toggled to full but it will toggle it to 24px.

Whats going on here?

Comment: @Matt Sorry it doesn't work, you can see in the inspector that it is working, it just doesn't set the full height, only sets it to 24px, take a look at the div through the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

[Wordpress runs jQuery](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) in [`noConflict` mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict), meaning that `$` is not aliased to `jQuery`. This means your `$(this.parentNode)[0].scrollHeight+'px'` throws an error (which you can see in the console).

Try;

```
jQuery(this.parentNode)[0].scrollHeight+'px'
```

... or, as your creating a jQuery object of a DOM Element, then accessing the DOM Element immediately, just:

```
this.parentNode.scrollHeight+'px'
```

... should suffice.